# Read TermVector of a specific document

Tags: lucene

Is there a way to read the term vector of a document along with the positions of each term?

During the creation of the index I am enabling the positions, freq etc

```
        FieldType fieldType = new FieldType();
        fieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);
        fieldType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
        fieldType.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
        fieldType.setStored(true);
```

while reading the search index, I am getting the Termvector using

Terms termVector=indexReader.getTermVector(docId, "content");
TermsEnum termsEnum = termVector.iterator();

The termsEnum seems to be unpositioned and I am not sure how to get the position value for each term of a document.

Appreciate anyone's help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think [TermPositionVector](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/TermPositionVector.html) and a little downcast may solve your problem. My lucene version is 3.6.2. The following code is written with **Scala**.

Assuming, you have **"we are family we not love"** in **contents** field of one document and we match the document successfully, then we begin to get every term with position.

```
val topDocs = iSearch.search("some query", 1).scoreDocs.toList

topDocs.foreach { matched =>

     val termVectors = indexReader.getTermFreqVector(matched.doc, "contents")
     // The field is added in document with TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS,
     // better write some try..catch to make this more robust
     val tpvector = termVectors.asInstanceOf[TermPositionVector]

     val termAndPosition = termVectors.getTerms.toList.map { term =>
        val indexOfTerm = termVectors.indexOf(term)

        //Returns an array of positions in which the term is found
        term -> tpvector.getTermPositions(indexOfTerm).toList
     }

     // Map(family -> List(2), love -> List(5), we -> List(0, 3))
     println(termAndPosition.toMap)

}
```

Basically, the term **are** will be omitted during indexing cause it's a stop word. The returned map actually makes sense, the term **we** appears in the position 0 and 3. If you want to get the OffSet, then the **getOffsets** method
in TermPositionVector is for your use.

Anyway, hope it helps.